# How to register for multiselect "item select" and "control collapse" events?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

How can I register for [multiselect](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/) "item selected" and "control collapse" events (when the [multiselect](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/) closes) and post back the selected items in my mvc3 controller so that I can update my grid results (based on the multiselect as a filter)?

Any jquery/ajax examples would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you need is on this demo page :) You just need to modify the code to add $.post

http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#callbacks

```
$("select").multiselect({
   click: function(event, ui){
      $callback.text(ui.value + ' ' + (ui.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked') );
              // item selected
              $.post("YourURL", { value: ui.value, state: ui.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'} );

   },
   close: function(){
      $callback.text("Select closed!");
              // select closed
   }
});
```

Comment: QQ: if I have multiple multiselects how can i tell what multiselect it came from?

Comment: you should be able to track back parent object of the event with $(this)